# Parsing a string containing backslash to list in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, list

I have a string:

```
str = '[\'RED\', \'GREEN\', \'BLUE\']'
```

I want to parse it to

```
list = ['RED','GREEN','BLUE']
```

But, I am unable to do so.

I tried to parse using json.loads:

```
json.loads(str)
```

It gave me:

```
{JSONDecodeError}Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Comment: That was easy. :(

Comment: For the record, @Ch3steR's solution is safer and I do prefer that one.

Comment: @learner Becareful while using `eval`. Using `eval` on untrusted strings can be dangerous. Use `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Check this blog post of Ned Batchelder [Eval really dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: @Ch3steR I have removed my answer and upvoted yours so that we can promote safer practices.

Comment: @dspencer Yes, for the community. ;) Thanks for the up.

Comment: You might want look at this @learner [eval vs ast.literal_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). `eval` can be dangerous on untrusted strings. You `ast.literal_eval` which evaluates only valid python structures.

```
import ast
s = '[\'RED\', \'GREEN\', \'BLUE\']'
ast.literal_eval(s)
# ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's in-built function [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). This works for conversion to python's other default data structures(dict, tuples, etc) as well.
Something like:

```
str = '[\'RED\', \'GREEN\', \'BLUE\']'
l = eval(str)
```